# How can I put API data into a global array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, async-await

I'm working on a very simple covid comparer project, and I've completed most of it but there is one problem. I want to push the result to a global array named data, but it's not working because the data is still loading when the data is pushed to the array. I've inserted the necessary code, not all of it.

```
var data = []; //global array
    function getData() {
 fetch(url + countryOne.value)
 .then(response => response.json())
  .then((result) => {
 var index = result.length - 1;
 var confirmed = result[index].Confirmed;
 textOne.textContent = result[index].CountryCode + " TOTAL CASES : " + confirmed;
 data.push(confirmed); //trying to push data

 
 })
 
    fetch(url + countryTwo.value)
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then((result) => {

 var index = result.length - 1;
 var confirmed = result[index].Confirmed;
 textTwo.textContent = result[index].CountryCode + " TOTAL CASES : " + confirmed;
 data.push(confirmed);
 
 })
 

}
```

As you can see I'm fetching the data, working with the response, and then pushing the data into a global array. The problem is that the data is not pushing into the array. I believe I'm having the problem because the array is pushing before the data from the api has loaded. How can push the data to the array after the data has loaded?

Comment: That fetch needs to run `.then` before you put that other fetch inside.

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Comment: Actually, I would put that last `fetch` inside the `.then` function above it, right after `data.push(confirmed);`.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it

Comment: You have a good point, it would only make sense to put the other fetch inside the then function. But I'm still looking for an answer...

Comment: The data that you expect is only available on an Asynchronous basis. Yes, that means any query to your `data` array that relies on the Asynchronous results must be done after the Asynchronous activity.

Comment: Yes correct, would you happen to know how I could await the data.push? I know I can use async and await but I need some sort of example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, `await` for fetch and push response details to `data`

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const data = [];

  const f1_data = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/")
    .then((res) => res.json());
  data.push(f1_data.name);

  const f2_data = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/")
    .then((res) => res.json());
  data.push(f2_data.name);
  
  console.log(data);
};

getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to see the following structure:

```js
async function getData(){
  const data = [];
  let resp, jsonArray;
  resp = await fetch(url+countryOne.value); jsonArray = await resp.json();
  let index = jsonArray.length-1, confirmed = jsonArray[index].Confirmed;
  textOne.textContent = jsonArray[index].CountryCode + ' TOTAL CASES : ' + confirmed;
  data.push(confirmed);
  resp = await fetch(url+countryTwo.value); jsonArray = await resp.json(); 
  index = jsonArray.length-1; confirmed = jsonArray[index].Confirmed;
  textTwo.textContent = jsonArray[index].CountryCode + ' TOTAL CASES : ' + confirmed;
  data.push(confirmed);
  return data;
}
// get like
getData().then(data=>{
  console.log(data);
});
// or in another async function
async function test(){
  const data = await getData();
  console.log(data);
}
test();
```

Comment: Doesn't work, but thanks

Comment: What doesn't work about it? `url`, `countryOne`, and `countryTwo` would have to be defined correctly. I really have no idea what your data looks like, besides what you've shown.

Comment: Yes I've defined them correctly